# Why does uniq -c command return duplicates in some cases?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, uniq

I am trying to `grep` for words in a file that is not present in another file

```
grep -v -w -i -r -f "dont_use_words.txt" "list_of_words.txt" >> inverse_match_words.txt


uniq -c -i inverse_match_words.txt | sort -nr
```

But I get duplicate values in my `uniq` command. Why so?

I am wondering if it might be because `grep` differentiates between strings, say, "AAA" found in "GIRLAAA", "AAABOY", "GIRLAAABOY" and therefore, I end up with duplicates.

When I do a `grep -F "AAA"` all of them are returned though.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me out on this. I am new to Linux OS.

Comment: Can you explain what  you're seeing vs what you expect to see with examples? uniq is for repeated lines in a file, is this a list of words all on seperate lines?

Answer (score 6):

`uniq` eliminates all but one line in each group of *consecutive* duplicate lines.  The conventional way to use it, therefore, is to pass the input through `sort` first.  You're not doing that, so yes, it is entirely possible that (non-consecutive) duplicates will remain in the output.

Example:

```
grep -v -w -i -f dont_use_words.txt list_of_words.txt \
  | sort -f \
  | uniq -c -i \
  | sort -nr
```